# Python ping-pong game, speeding up the ball after paddle hit

Tags: python

I'm new here and I'm the beginner. I've been learning programming since 5 months and as the main language I've decided to stick to python. I wrote my first simple game which is ping-pong (based on yt tutorials) and I want to improve it a bit by speeding up the ball after each paddle hit and comes back to normal speed when scored. I know that I put ball.dx +=1 in wrong place. It speeds up tho, but only when ball goes up. When it goes down, it comes back to normal speed and of course the speed is looped and even if scored, it still speeds up. Appreciate for any help.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("gra by mati")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)


# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.color("white")
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)


# ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.shape("square")
ball.speed(0)
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 1/5
ball.dy = 1/5

# Pen
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("Player A: 0  Player B: 0", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

# Score
score_a = 0
score_b = 0




# Function
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_b_up():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddle_b.sety(y)






#keyboard biding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")   
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")   

# Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    # move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # border checking
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1


    if ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 390: 
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_a += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}  Player B: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))


    if ball.xcor() < -390: 
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_b += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}  Player B: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))


    # paddle and ball collision
    if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() -40):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx +=1
        ball.dx *= -1





    if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() -40):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball.dx +=1
        ball.dx *= -1
```

Comment: It seems to me after a brief glance that you are calling `ball.dx += 1`, but you are also reversing the direction each hit, so when hit one way it should be `ball.dx -= 1` instead. This would explain why it "goes back to normal speed"...

Comment: Thanks vmuch! That was a small detail and I could not figure it out. It works fine now and also comes back to normal speed - I've added ball.dx = 0.15 and ball.dx = -0.15 to border checking. It makes sense for me but I still do not understand why the value for speed is minus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reviewing your game a bit I found an error that the ball would "stick" to the paddle on the left side, and like you said the speed did not reset each score. I've adjusted it in a few places and it seems much improved.

Firstly I reset the speed every time there was a score:

```
if ball.xcor() > 390:
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx = 1 / 5 # reset to initial speed
    score_a += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write("Player A: {}  Player B: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

if ball.xcor() < -390:
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx = 1 / 5 # reset to initial speed
    ball.dx *= -1
    score_b += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write("Player A: {}  Player B: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
```

I think this could be improved by having a variable at the top like `initial_speed = 1/5` and then you can put `ball.dx = initial_speed` everywhere it resets. This allows you to only change one number at the top of your program and it will adjust the speed everywhere, preventing you to have to hunt down everywhere you reset it every time!

Secondly I fixed the paddle collision a little bit

```
if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() -40):
    ball.setx(340)
    ball.dx *= -1 # flip direction first
    ball.dx -=1 # speed it up

if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() -40):
    ball.setx(-340)
    ball.dx *= -1
    ball.dx +=1
```

Again this could be improved by making a variable `speed_up_by = 1` and then using `ball.dx += speed_up_by` to easily adjust it. I think that 1 is far too large of a number and you won't be able to get more than 5 hits in (if you're lucky). To answer your comment about why one is `ball.dx +=1` and the other is `ball.dx -=1` I urge you to think about it in numbers. The initial speed is .2 (or 1/5), and then after it hits on the right side you should reverse it (to -.2 and now it is traveling left) and then increase its speed (by minusing 1 -> -1.2). Now when it gets to the other side you reverse it again (to 1.2) and then increase its speed (by adding 1 -> 2.2). You can see that even though we are subtracting from the speed it actually *increases* the magnitude of the speed!! I think this also shows you that increasing the speed by 1 each hit is insanely large. After the first hit the ball is going **6 times** as fast as the initial speed!!! After 2 hits it is going **11 times** the initial speed!!! You probably want to increase the magnitude of speed by .1 each time. That makes it so after 1 hit the speed is only 1.5 times initial speed. After 2 hits, the speed is twice the initial speed...and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your advices are very valuable for me and now I understand it better. Still have to learn a lot as I get confused sometimes when it comes to math. I have marked your answer as the best but unfortunately I cannot vote because apparently this option is available from 15 points of reputation. Thanks once again !